# Store custom type object in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm using: **gustavofao** library for parsing json.

`Resource.java`:

```
public interface Resource extends Parcelable {
    String getId();
    void setId(String id);
    String getType();
    void setType(String type);
    Links getLinks();
    void setLinks(Links links);
}
```

I've a class called `Base.kt`:

```
public interface BaseInterface extends Parcelable {
    String getId();
    void setId(String id);
    String getType();
    void setType(String type);
    Links getLinks();
    void setLinks(Links links);
}

public class Base implements BaseInterface {
    ....
}
```

Then I create an data class `CustomDataClass.kt`

```
@Type(...)
@Parcelize open class CustomDataClass(
        @SerialName("name") var name: String,
        @SerialName("lastname") var lastname: String,
) : RealmObject(), Resource {
    //@SerialName("item") var testItem: Resource ?= null
    @IgnoredOnParcel @PrimaryKey private lateinit var id: String
    @IgnoredOnParcel @Ignore private lateinit var links: Links

    constructor() : this("","")

    companion object {
        const val TYPE = "xxx"
    }

    override fun getId(): String {
        //
    }

    override fun setId(id: String) {
        //
    }

    override fun getType(): String {
        return TYPE
    }

    override fun setType(type: String?) {
        //
    }

    override fun getLinks(): Links {
        //
    }

    override fun setLinks(links: Links) {
        //
    }
}
```

I've to get a field with name `"item"` from JSON response. The content can be three objects: `A`, `B` or `C`. All three objects `.. extend BaseResource`

So, basically, what I do is, I add `@SerialName("item") var testItem: Resource ?= null` as a property to my `CustomDataClass`, but, I get an error:

`error: Field "testItem" of type "com.gustavofao.jsonapi.Models.Resource" is not supported.`

It's from Realm... Does it really not support custom types? What's my alternative in this case?

How can I define my custom type object and insert it in DB, so Realm is not screaming? :)

Comment: if you have any custom object inside custom model which extends RealmObject for that you also need to extend with RealmObject. In you case does Resource extends ReamObject ?

Comment: @KrishnaSharma Didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: share this class please **com.gustavofao.jsonapi.Models.Resource**

Comment: Consider not re-using the API response as a DB schema.

Comment: @KrishnaSharma Updated. It's class from library. :)
EpicPandaForce Why?